# Cheap approximate integer division on a GPU

Tags: cuda, integer-division, approximate

So, I want to divide me some 32-bit unsigned integers on a GPU, and I don't care about getting an exact result. In fact, let's be lenient and suppose I'm willing to accept a multiplicative error factor of upto 2, i.e. if q = x/y I'm willing to accept anything between 0.5*q and 2*q.

I haven't yet measured anything, but it seems to me that something like this (CUDA code) should be useful:

```
__device__ unsigned cheap_approximate_division(unsigned dividend, unsigned divisor)
{
    return 1u << (__clz(dividend) - __clz(divisor));
}
```

it uses the ["find first (bit) set" integer intrinsic](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-math-api/group__CUDA__MATH__INTRINSIC__INT.html#group__CUDA__MATH__INTRINSIC__INT_1gaf1eb22243e29e0b7222adee8ae7d4e4) as a cheap base-2-logarithm function.

**Notes:** I could make this non-32-bit-specific but then I'd have to complicate the code with templates, wrap `__clz()` with a templated function to use `__clzl()` and `__clzll()` etc.

Questions:

- Is there a better method for such approximate division, in terms of clock cycles? Perhaps with slightly different constraints?
- If I want better accuracy, should I stay with integers or should I just go through floating-point arithemtic?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Going via floating point gives you a much more precise result, slightly lower instruction count on most architectures, and potentially a higher throughput:

```
__device__ unsigned cheap_approximate_division(unsigned dividend, unsigned divisor)
{
   return (unsigned)(__fdividef(dividend, divisor) /*+0.5f*/ );
}
```

The `+0.5f` in the comment shall indicate that you can also turn the float->int conversion into proper rounding at essentially no cost other than higher energy consumption (it turns an `fmul` into an `fmad` with the constant coming straight from the constant cache). Rounding would take you further away from the exact integer result though.

Comment: Can you throw some cycle counts here? Assuming all those integer operations I used are 1 cycle per warp, and everything is in registers, then I should be using just 4; how many cycles is this version?

Comment: Sorry, you'll have to benchmark yourself atm. Keep in mind however that [`__ffs()` compiles to a multiple instruction emulation sequence on newer architectures](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#arithmetic-instructions). Are you targeting a specific architecture?

Comment: @einpoklum if you migrate to opencl for GCN, it emulates integer division by fp on backend too. Fp must be the fastest option.